# CMake Linking Instructions

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to link a shared object on my executable with an executable in my cmake project.

my `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
project (proto_app)

add_executable( helloDemo hello.cpp )
add_executable( faissDemo 1-Flat.cpp )
```

My executable `faissDemo` doesn't compile like this because the shared object is not linked. The shared object is located in `/usr/local/lib/libfaiss.so`. My question is how should I link to the shared object in CMake?

I can compile `1-Flat.cpp` successfully from the command line like: 
`$ g++ 1-Flat.cpp -L /usr/local/lib/ -lfaiss`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the dir to the `link_directories` and add the lib as `target_link_libraries`:

```
 cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
 project (proto_app)

 link_directories(/usr/local/lib)     

 add_executable( helloDemo hello.cpp )
 add_executable( faissDemo 1-Flat.cpp )
 target_link_libraries(faissDemo faiss)
```

Comment: you mean `link_directories` right? Worked!

Comment: @mkuse Sorry, yes...

Comment: Why not just `target_link_libraries(faissDemo /usr/local/lib/libfaiss.so)`

Comment: @Bernhard My personal preference is not to use absolute paths in target_link_libraries if it is an installed lib.

Comment: I have to DV this answer, because `link_directories` is heavily discouraged in CMake, for good reason (it can break dependency tracking, among other things). The preferred alternative is to use absolute paths to libs in `target_link_libraries`. See [note in CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/link_directories.html).

Comment: @Angew You would be right if /usr/local/lib  would be a private lib path but it isn't. it is a system path.

Comment: @user6556709 Even libraries on a system path can change and require re-linking their downstream.